# Products per row at bigcartel shop

Tags: row, product, bigcartel

is there any way to change products in row from 3 to 4 products per row in bigcartel shop with NEAT Theme?

I have alreday looked at the code, but didnt find anything that could help with it, also I didnt find any infomantion in the internet about it

Thank you, Dominik